# regex match if starts or ends with whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match my string if it starts with any number of whitespaces or ends with any number of spaces:

my current regex includes also the spaces inbetween:

```
(^|\s+)|(\s+|$)
```

how can I fix it to reach my goal?

### update:

this doesn't work, because it matches the spaces.
I want to select the whole string or line rather, if it starts with or ends with whitespace(s).

Comment: `/^(\s.*|.*\s)$/` should work for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

modify it to the following

```
(^\s+)|(\s+$)
```

---

Based on modified OP, Use this Pattern `^\s*(.*?)\s*$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1bjGDe/2) look at capturing group #1

```
^               # Start of string/line
\s              # <whitespace character>
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  .             # Any character except line break
  *?            # (zero or more)(lazy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
\s              # <whitespace character>
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
$               # End of string/line
```

Comment: Mr. Down-Voter would you care to explain!!

Comment: this doesn't work, because it matches the spaces.
I want to select the whole string or line rather, if it starts with or ends with whitespace(s).

Comment: @cplus, you need to clarify that in your OP, and not down vote arbitrarily.

Comment: @cplus, modified my answer above!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:
https://regex101.com/r/gTQS5g/1

```
^\s|\s$
```

---

Or with `.trim()` you could do without the regex:

```
myStr !== myStr.trim()
```

Comment: this doesn't work, because it matches the spaces.
I want to select the whole string or line rather, if it starts with or ends with whitespace(s).

Answer (score 1):

modify it to the regex below

```
(^\s+.*)|(.*\s+$)
```

you can check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xxwbOA/1)

Comment: this doesn't work, because it matches the spaces.
I want to select the whole string or line rather, if it starts with or ends with whitespace(s).

Comment: added a demo which matches the whole string

Answer (score 1):

No need to create groups. You can create one alternation.

```
^\s+|\s+$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/pdHkWU/1)

Comment: this doesn't work, because it matches the spaces.
I want to select the whole string or line rather, if it starts with or ends with whitespace(s).

Answer (score 0):

this could help you , see [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/oiRQWJ/1)

```
^\s+.*|.*\s+$
```